# MySQL/PHP - Return Closest Numerical Match

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make an order form where user can choose a clothing size. I have all the available sizes stored in a database, as `code`, `size` and `category`.

`size` is formatted like `66/68/76` (Waist/Hips/Leg Length). User is able to input these three values. If user's size is available - there's no problem. But if it's not I want the site to offer or change it to nearest available size. For example if user entered 65/66/74 and exact value doesn't exist (or unavailable right now) it will be changed to 66/65/74.

Comment: How many sizes per each do you want to go up/down? Is the size stored as 3 separate things or as one?

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "closest".

Comment: @SamSwift웃 There isn't a limit, just the closest match, whether that be up or down, as we waist for example ranges from 66 to 85. And they are stored as one

Comment: @PeeHaa, the OP just answered that ;P

Comment: @GordonLinoff By closest, I mean for example if a user entered 74/75/90. It would first look at waist, closest matches are 72 and 75. So it would then look at all sizes beginning with 75/*/*. Then it would select hips, so we have 75/72/* and 75/76/* so it would select the latter. And so on with the legs

Comment: @SamSwift웃 oh yeah... :P

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Do it yourself, and afterwards if you still have problems, *then* ask for help.

Comment: I'd do it myself if I knew how too. @buffjape

Comment: So learn how to code before you release something like online store. Right now it sounds like asking somebody about passing your driving exam, arguing that if you knew how to drive, you would have passed the exam yourself. The task here is pretty easy to solve with basic knowledge of any programming language.

Comment: @Cheslab I'm not releasing anything, this is an internal project in aid of reducing paperwork, and lets be fair here, some people learn in different ways - I personally learn from seeing something in context then adapting for my own use. If I don't know how to do something, how am I going to researching a specific method if I don't know what it is in the first place.

Comment: Any way of studying is good if you learn something in the end. But definition of word "help" includes other people's participation added to _your_ efforts. In this particular situation you didn't stumble upon a piece of code that you can analyze and learn something from it. You asked somebody to write this code. There is a difference. All I want to say is when you're providing code and show people what have you done so far it is much more pleasant for other people to help. This applies to literacy too. Any way, I reformulated the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what you mean by "closest".  Along the way, you should also store the three values in three different columns.  Storing multiple values in a single column is a bad idea.

Sometimes, one is stuck with a particular data format because of someone else's poor design decisions.

One perhaps reasonable measure is Euclidean distance -- the sum of the squares of each component.  You can calculate this in MySQL:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             substring_index(size, '/', 1) as waist,
             substring_index(substring_index(size, '/', 2), '/', -1) as hips,
             substring_index(size, '/', -1) as legs
      from t
     ) t
order by pow(waist - $waist, 2) + pow(hips - $hips, 2) + pow(legs - $legs, 2)
limit 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain this in more context, I'm a complete amateur at this. So for example, if I have a variable $size which is a textbox POST, how would I then prepare such variable to run in this query?

Answer (score 0):

One way whould be to store 3 values as an integer 666876 (66/68/76).

Then, you can do a query of the minimun value of the substraction of `productSize - userSize`, that is greater than 0.

This approach takes always the clothing higher size.